Some kanji characters cannot be displayed when using TCPDF
I am using TCPDF latest version (6.7.5) to export PDF documents. In the document there are some Japanese kanji characters that cannot be displayed.
I have tried using fonts like cid0jp, cid0cs, cid0cs, arialuni, ... but it still doesn't work. I also download Japanese fonts and add them to the library but the result is still the same. Below is the demo.php file and the result is an empty pdf file:
<?php 
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

$pdf->AddPage();

$string = "         ";
$pdf->SetFont('cid0jp', '', 12);
$pdf->Cell(190, 10, $string, 0, 11);

$pdf->Output();

Please give me some advice or some examples for my case. Thanks a lot.

Don't use cid0jp, it's not an actual font. Use a font that contains Japanese characters.

I also tried using a font with Japanese characters but it still didn't work

Which font did you try?

A lot of:
droidsansfallback, Noto_Sans_JP, genjyuugothiclpnormal, gen-jyuu-gothic, NotoSansCJKjp, wts11.ttf, arialuni.ttf, nagayama_kai08.ttf, ...

other japanese characters is ok. But           not shown.

@KJ Not supporting characters beyond the Unicode BMP is a limitation of TCPDF, not of the PDF format.

can you try this line $string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8'); after the $string variable.

FWIW the crux of the issue seems to be that while the relatively compact JP Katakana and Hiragana alphabets are within the range of Unicode that can be represented by 2-byte UTF16 sequences, all Kanji are above that range and require a 4-byte UTF16 sequence, which is where TCPDF seems to have its issue due to its internal encoding handling.

@Sammitch "all Kanji are above that range" Nope, common kanji are located in the CJK Unified Ideographs block (BMP plane). The OP wants rare kanji located in the CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B block (SIP plane).
